# Get the result based on current year in oracle

Tags: oracle

[I have created a table with 2 columns as shown in figure. I want to select the rows based on **current year**.

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( NAME VARCHAR2(1),  DT TIMESTAMP(3) );

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘A’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-04 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘A’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-05 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘A’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2020-02-04 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘A’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2020-02-05 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));
```

I have queried the below query like

```
SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE DT = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

I am getting errors...I was not able to get expected result as shown in pic][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFfWB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extract` does not take a format model. It simply extracts the year from a date (as a number, like 2020). So, one simple way would be to write:

```
... where extract(year from dt) = extract(year from sysdate)
```

A better way, because it doesn't call a function repeatedly (one call per row), and it allows the use of an index on column `dt` if there is one, is to write it like this:

```
... where dt >= trunc(sysdate, 'year') 
      and dt <  add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'year'), 12)
```

`trunc(sysdate, 'year')` truncates `sysdate` to the beginning of the year; `add_monhts` adds months (in this case, 12 months, to get the beginning of **next** year).